# Expand / scale camera frustum

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to work out how to expand the camera frustum for some intersection logic that I'm working on.

In short, I need to work out what objects fall not only within the camera frustum, but also that fall within a certain buffer surrounding the camera frustum. The best way I can think of to achieve this is to expand the camera frustum in some way before running the intersection checks.

However, I can't think how best to achieve this. I'm also unsure if there's a better alternative for achieving the same result. I guess if I could find the distance from an object to the nearest frustum plane then that could also work.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading my question I realised that my first port of call should have been to look at how `Frustum.intersectsBox()` works. It turns out it had everything I needed and by introducing a `buffer` argument I can effectively expand the frustum by providing a buffer value in world units.

```
const frustumIntersect = (() => {
  const p = new THREE.Vector3()

  return (frustum, box, buffer = 0) => {
    const planes = frustum.planes

    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i ++) {

      const plane = planes[i]

      p.x = plane.normal.x > 0 ? box.max.x : box.min.x
      p.y = plane.normal.y > 0 ? box.max.y : box.min.y
      p.z = plane.normal.z > 0 ? box.max.z : box.min.z

      if (plane.distanceToPoint(p) < 0 - buffer) {
        return false
      }
    }

    return true
  }
})()
```

Which would be called like so to include objects within a 200 unit buffer around the frustum:

```
frustumIntersect(frustum, yourBox3, 200)
```